# What is the simplest (fastest) material for rendering simple 2D images?

Tags: rendering, materials, 2d

I am rendering a simple 2D animation. As you can see in the image below, each frame consists of a white background with black circles moving over it. Right now I'm coloring the circles using "Principled BSDF" and the white background using "Emission". It looks nice but it takes several seconds to render each frame, which I think it's way too much for such a simple image (I'm not working in a slow machine).

Is there a different material (or technique) I can use to create this simple image, but using less time to render?

Sample frame:

[image: Sample frame]

Comment: Are you rendering this in Cycles or Eevee? How are you creating the black dots?

Comment: @RonJensen The black dots are circles made using bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(). I have tried rendering in Cycles and it was much much faster, but the dots look weird, not black at all.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Emission shader will draw the exact RGB selected on screen. Use this for both materials.

Then, make sure to turn your samples all the way down as that's what's really going to make a difference. Consider reducing the detail of your circles, especially if they are spheres.